# PHP import csv file UTF8 with BOM

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I'm trying to write PHP script for importing CSV files.

I'm using this code:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="f"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($_FILES['f']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $data = array_map("utf8_encode", $data); //added
        $num = count($data);
        // Row
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { 
                // Column      
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Script works, but the problem is with encoding characters. In CSV files content is in latvian language, and it shows latvian characters incorrectly.

Some latvian text example:

> Šis ir septītais kāzu fotokonkurss Latvijā, turklāt, pēc iesūtīto
>   fotogrāfiju skaita tas ir arī lielākais visā Baltijā. Šajā
>   fotokonkursā piedalījās 90 autori, kuri iesūtīja kopumā 1106
>   fotogrāfiju. Fotokonkursa apbalvošanas laikā tiks nominēti labākie
>   Latvijas kāzu fotogrāfi 10 dažādās kategorijās: gatavošanās,
>   ceremonija, emocijas, bērni, portrets, jaunais pāris, detaļas,
>   svinības, izšķirošais mirklis un gaismas spēles.

And that is what I receive from script:

> Ðis ir septîtais kâzu fotokonkurss Latvijâ turklât pçc iesûtîto
>   fotogrâfiju skaita tas ir arî lielâkais visâ Baltijâ. Ðajâ
>   fotokonkursâ piedalîjâs 90 autori kuri iesûtîja kopumâ 1106
>   fotogrâfiju. Fotokonkursa apbalvoðanas laikâ tiks nominçti labâkie
>   Latvijas kâzu fotogrâfi 10 daþâdâs kategorijâs: gatavoðanâs,
>   ceremonija, emocijas, bçrni, portrets, jaunais pâris, detaïas,
>   svinîbas, izðíiroðais mirklis un gaismas spçles.

When I simply do `echo 'Some latvian text';` it works fine. So the problem is with csv handler.
**As far as I know, I need to use UTF8 with BOM**. But how can I do this?

Comment: You could use something like: https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8 to remove the BOM first, then import it.

Comment: Why are you using `utf8_encode`? Have you tried without it? What is the encoding of the input file? If you're unsure, open it in a text editor which allows you to open the file in different encodings, and try opening it with different encodings until you hit one which interprets the file correctly.

Comment: If I will not use `utf8_encode`, I will receive question symbols instead of letters like: `R��ina` . I'm saving CSV files via Excel. Tried also create files with Notepad++, set charset to UTF8, UTF8 with bom, nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got you right mb_convert_encoding might be what you are looking for.

```
mb_convert_encoding($data, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-15");
```

Not sure about the ISO-Code.
Maybe this helps: http://webcheatsheet.com/html/character_sets_list.php

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: `$ex = iconv("ISO-8859-13", "UTF-8", $data[$c]); ` resolves the problem :)